# No module named 'lstm_object_detection' in tensorflow /model/research/lstm_object_detection

Tags: python, tensorflow

I gitcloned `lstm` from tensorflow research models. Running `seq_dataset_builder.py` from inputs file the following error appears

> No module named 'lstm_object_detection'.

The line making the error is

```
from lstm_object_detection.inputs import tf_sequence_example_decoder
```

`lstm_object_detection/inputs` is the directory of the python script file.

My tensorflow version is 1.7.0 and the file is run on python3.

I also can't import tensorflow.google.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be that Python doesn't find the lstm_object_detection in your path

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.getcwd()) # add current directory to your path
from lstm_object_detection.inputs import tf_sequence_example_decoder
```

To check the paths where Python looks for modules use:

```
import sys
for path in sys.path: 
     print(path)
```